# WebBrowser1.Navigate loop request

Tags: vb.net

How can i make this code to loop urls continuously in Webbrowser1, after run trough these links one time.

This is the code i have so far, but when i run this, the Webbrowser stop with last url, wich is google.com. What i want to do is when the last url is reached i want it to start from top again, and run trough links again and again, until i exit the program.

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents backgroundWorker1 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Dim l As New List(Of String)
Dim flagDC As Boolean = False

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Hide()
    Button3.Show()
    l = New List(Of String)
    l.Add("http://bbc.com/sipeu/php/zq.php")
    l.Add("http://google.com")
    l.Add("http://DCWC.com/sipeu/us.php")
    l.Add("http://google.com")
    l.Add("http://example.com/sipeu/v.php")
    l.Add("http://google.com")

    backgroundWorker1 = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                     ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
                                     Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For Each www In l
        flagDC = False
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(www)
        Do

        Loop While Not flagDC



    Next

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
                                          Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    flagDC = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button3.Hide()
    ChangeUserAgent("troll001_v2-agent34")

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://example.com/welcome.php")


End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use a [**`Timer`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and keep track of the current index in a variable.